# How should I connect this meter to my power inverter?

Tags: meter

Is there anyone here knows how to install this on an inverter? I haven't been able to locate an instruction manual.

[image]
Top Picture grabbed from the internet

.
[image]
Actual picture of unit I have

Comment: There's a wiring diagram on the right side.  What else do you need to know?

Comment: I can't understand the wiring diagram. All I know is I need to connect it in between of Grid and Solar Inverter

Comment: this page has a link for contacting the manufacturer .... http://www.chintmeter.com/industrial-instruments-panel-meter/din-rail-energy-meter/din-rail-kwh-meter-single-phase.html

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: The wiring diagram in the top picture is different from the wiring diagram in the bottom picture. I assume the bottom one is your actual unit, and the top is just some random web picture? Is that correct? It looks like you have a manual there with installation instructions.

Comment: There seem to be several versions of very similar products which wire up in slightly different ways. Some seem to have integrated current transformers, and some seem to use external current transformers.

Comment: @mkeith you are right. The top picture is from web and the bottom is actual unit. The manual shown on the bottom picture is the manual for my inverter not the manual for meter. I have manual for meter but it only shows the same diagram as what is printed on the actual unit. That's all, no elaboration on how to connect it between inverter and grid

Comment: Watch this video to see if it helps. Basically, the voltage connection to the meter is for voltage sensing only. The current transformer measures current on the single wire passing through the hole. Watch this video.
https://help.ekmmetering.com/support/solutions/articles/6000124129-how-to-install-an-omnimeter-video-

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the labeling and instructions which were part of the equipment's UL, TUV, ETF etc. listing... *nope, could not keep a straight face.*

Seriously, the labeling and instructions that is actually on your equipment.  If that's the lower picture, then the current transformer goes on 5 and 6, line to 1 and 2, and neutral to 3 and 4.

Do not daisy chain, that is don't bring "line in" into 1, and "line out" into 2, unless ***your*** diagram tells you to (such as in your first picture). In the lower pictured unit, you need to put pigtail wires on line 1 and 2, and use an appropriate 4-wire splicing device to join those pigtails to line in and line out (4 wires in total). Likewise lines 3 and 4.  Note the instruction may be different for line vs neutral.  That's for a reason.